# I am trying to create an ASM program for an x86 processor that converts Celsius into Fahrenheit, but I keep getting a segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have been working on an assembly program that takes Celsius and outputs Fahrenheit using real numbers. Celsius is inputted from the keyboard. Whenever I run the program on the console, it outputs the request, but any input results in a segmentation fault.
Where is the error causing this?

```
section .data                          
request: db "Enter a temperature in Celsius:", 0

format_in db "%d", 0

celsius: times 4 db 0 

format_out_2     db      "farenheit = %f",0x0a, 0x00  

x   dd  1.8   ;dword
y   dd  32.0  ;dword
z   dd  0     ;dword
temp    dq  0     ;qword
    
    
section .text                          ; Code section.

  extern scanf 
  extern printf                        ; the C function to be called
  global main                      ; "C" main program

main:                      

;  Ask for an integer value for celsius
  push request                         
  call printf
  add esp, 4                           
 
; Read user input
  push celsius 
  push format_in 
  call scanf    
  add esp, 8    
 
  mov eax, [celsius]
  call c2f
  
  push eax
  fld   dword [eax]                    
  fstp  qword [temp]                  
  
  push  dword [temp + 4]           
  push  dword [temp]
  push  dword format_out_2        
  call  printf                 
  add   esp, 12                
  
  mov   eax, 1                     
  mov   ebx, 0
  int   0x80
   
c2f:
  fld   dword [x]                 
  fld   dword [eax]
  fmul
  fstp   dword [z]  ; store mul in z as a dword
  
  fld   dword [z]
  fld   dword [y]
  fadd
  fstp  dword [eax] ; store the addition of z and y into eax           
  
  ret
```

Comment: `mov eax, [celsius] ... fld dword [eax]`: Think about what this does.

Comment: Also, learn to use a debugger. Other problems: you read an integer with `%d` so you want to `fild` it (or read a float). You want `fmulp` and `faddp` because you unbalance the fpu stack and there is little reason to store to `z` then reload it immediately. Do not use the a system call to terminate the program. Depending on environment you might need to keep stack pointer 16 byte aligned.